# Numeric value issues with high values, not with low values

Tags: php, numeric, bbpress

The code (the issue occurs on the third line):

```
$post_count = bbp_get_topic_reply_count();
$post_count = $post_count++;
$page_count = round($post_count / 15 );

if (!empty($_POST['jump_page'])) {
    $jump_page  = $_POST['jump_page'];
    $topic_id   = bbp_get_topic_id();
    header('Location: https://url/?p=' . $topic_id . '&paged=' . $jump_page);
}
if ( $page_count > 4) {
//do something
```

When `$page_count` gives a low value there is no problem.
Don't know exactly when, but when `$page_count` is supposed to give a high value I get the following Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /.../...

I tried replacing `15`with a string and `round($post_count / 15)` with:

- `intdiv($post_count, 15)`
- `var_dump(round($post_count / 15)`
- `var_dump(int_div($post_count, 15)`

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say that you don't know exactly when the break happens, but do you have an example of one `$post_count` value that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: Working: http://vespa-ciao.nl/beta/forums/topic/je-uitlaat-collectie-topic/
And not working: http://vespa-ciao.nl/beta/forums/topic/je-laatste-aanwinst/

Comment: How large is that value? I can't replicate the issue https://3v4l.org/f04VZ . The only way I can replicate it is using a string value https://3v4l.org/PVdmK

Comment: `$post_count = $post_count++;` doesn't make sense. Either `$post_count = $post_count + 1;` or `$post_count++;`, but not both together.

Comment: What does `var_dump($post_count);` show when you get the error? See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%22a+non+well+formed+numeric+value%22

Comment: @Andreas: I now echo the value at the top of every page because the're always different, You'll see them if you visit again.
@Barmar; You're correct, `$post_count++` is what I had, but trying to fix the issue I ended up with this stupid piece of code, I've corrected it.

Comment: echo-ing the values also made the issue clear to me.. `bbp_get_topic_reply_count()` gives of a value with a comma. So I added `str_replace(',', '', bbp_get_topic_reply_count());` and that fixed everything.. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those stumbling onto this post, this was the solution:

`bbp_get_topic_reply_count()` gives of a value with a comma. So I changed:

```
$post_count = bbp_get_topic_reply_count();
$post_count = $post_count++;
$page_count = round($post_count / 15 );
```

into

```
$post_count = str_replace(',', '', bbp_get_topic_reply_count());
$post_count++;
$page_count = ceil($post_count / 15 );
```